# IIS 7.5 with PHP 5.3, displaying errors on page

Tags: php, iis

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2, with IIS 7.5 and PHP 5.3 (configured by FastCGI). In my `php.ini` I have:

```
log_errors = On
display_errors = Off
error_log = syslog      (also tried an actual file with appropriate permissions)
```

Each time a page contains an error, it is never logged anywhere, but it is displayed on the page (unless I turn `log_errors` off). I'm guessing that the `stderr` from `php-cgi.exe` is being put on the page, instead of being logged where it is supposed to be. Is there a setting somewhere that allows me to log these errors properly?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the PHP 5.3 installation and instead chose to install PHP 5.4 manually using the zip file rather than using the MSI installer. From there, the same configuration as mentioned in the question allowed PHP to log correctly. Perhaps it was a version mismatch or something.